# VMWare snapshot took server offline

Tags: vmware

When taking a VMWare snapshot of our web server (IIS) the web server went offline, is there a specific way to take a snapshot that would prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting,Do you have SQL server along with IIS Server?I think due to high I/O it freeze your VM and makes your webserver to offline.Do you have a space in VM datastore?

Try to take snapshot without quiescent point(experimental purpose).